# Хочу узнать как можно оптимизировать написаный мною код на c++

Tags: c++, оптимизация

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


double** prodMatrsloj(double** a, double** b, int n1, int m1, int n2, int m2)
{
double** res;
int i, j;
res = new double* [n1];
for (i = 0; i < m2; i++)
{
    res[i] = new double[m2];
}

for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        res[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < m1; k++)
            res[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        res[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < m1; k++)
            res[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
    }
}

return res;
 }


double** prodMatrumnoja(double** a, double** b, int n1, int m1, int n2, int m2, int l)
{
double** res;
int i, j;
res = new double* [n1];
for (i = 0; i < m2; i++)
{
    res[i] = new double[m2];
}


for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        res[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < m1; k++)
            res[i][j] = a[i][j] * l;
    }
}


for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        res[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < m1; k++)
            res[i][j] = a[i][j] * l;
    }
}
return res;
   }

 double** prodMatrumnojb(double** a, double** b, int n1, int m1, int n2, int m2, int l)
 {
double** res;
int i, j;
res = new double* [n1];
for (i = 0; i < m2; i++)
{
    res[i] = new double[m2];
}


for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        res[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < m1; k++)
            res[i][j] = b[i][j] * l;
    }
}


for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        res[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < m1; k++)
            res[i][j] = b[i][j] * l;
    }
}
return res;
}


double** prodMatr(double** a, double** b, int n1, int m1, int n2, int m2)
{
double** res;
int i, j;
res = new double* [n1];
for (i = 0; i < m2; i++)
{
    res[i] = new double[m2];
}

for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        res[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < m1; k++)
            res[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        res[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < m1; k++)
            res[i][j] += a[i][j] * b[k][j];
    }
}

return res;
}

  int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int n1, n2, m1, m2;
int i, j, l;
double** a, ** b, ** c;
ifstream file1, file2;

file1.open("matr1.txt");
file2.open("matr2.txt");
cout << "Введите количество строк матрицы 1: ";
cin >> n1;
cout << "Введите количество столбцов матрицы 1: ";
cin >> m1;
cout << "Введите количество строк матрицы 2: ";
cin >> n2;
cout << "Введите количество столбцов матрицы 2: ";
cin >> m2;
cout << "Введите число на которое нужно умножить матрицы: ";
cin >> l;

if (m1 != n2)
{
    cout << "умножение/сложение матриц невозможно\n";
    return 0;
}

a = new double* [n1];
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    a[i] = new double[m1];
}

b = new double* [n2];
for (i = 0; i < n2; i++)
{
    b[i] = new double[m2];
}

for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m1; j++)
    {
        file1 >> a[i][j];
        cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;

for (i = 0; i < n2; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        file2 >> b[i][j];
        cout << b[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;
file1.close();
file2.close();

cout << "результат сложения матриц: " << "\n";
c = prodMatrsloj(a, b, n1, m1, n2, m2);
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        cout << c[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << "\n";
cout << "результат умножение матриц на число: " << "\n";
c = prodMatrumnoja(a, b, n1, m1, n2, m2, l);
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        cout << c[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << "\n";
c = prodMatrumnojb(a, b, n1, m1, n2, m2, l);
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        cout << c[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << "\n";
cout << "результат умножения матриц: " << "\n";
c = prodMatr(a, b, n1, m1, n2, m2);
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m2; j++)
    {
        cout << c[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Где описание того, что программа должна делать? Какую задачу она решает? Зачем вообще на С++ решать задачи в стиле С, если есть классы, векторы и т.п. вещи?

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что я правильно понял твою программу, но у тебя в функциях вроде как одни и те же циклы записаны по два раза, это странно.
И чисто для красоты в тех случаях, когда у нас в теле цикла одна строчка кода можно опускать фигурные скобки:

```
for(int i = 0;.....)
   cout << ... << endl;
```

И чисто вкусовщина, я бы работал с векторами, они приятнее в использовании